# Permission denied while running maven command jenkins

Tags: jenkins, permission-denied

I am facing permission denied issues while running a maven `clean test` on a pom.xml present in /home/tes/pom.xml from jenkins. Any suggestions

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins
[jenkins] $ /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn -f /home/tes/pom.xml clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (/home/tes/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM /home/tes/pom.xml: /home/tes/pom.xml (Permission denied)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: check permissions of pom.xml and other files

Comment: you have to grant at least "read" permission for the user, which runs jenkins job on the machine- eg. `sudo chmod -R +r` <path>, `chmod -R +r /home/tes/` maybe also +x permission, I am not sure
Probably the more correct way will be to create some usergroup on machine and set permission per that group

Answer (score 2):

Just grant read access for all to the pom.xml file:

```
chmod +r /home/tes/pom.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the reason was that I did not have JDK, but just JRE configured in JAVA_HOME of the Global Tool Configuration > JDK > JDK Installation. As a matter of fact Jenkins warns you that the path is not pointing to something containing a JDK.

JDK is needed for some Plugins, like Maven Integration or Docker Pipeline, as [Java requirements](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/#:%7E:text=Generally%2C%20Jenkins%20allows%20ANY%20version,be%20invoked%20during%20the%20build.) section in Jenkins documentation states. So this must checked because it surprisingly results in the weird error:

```
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/celsus_0-1-0^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0c533cf2327a416a254afa2348abafe7790ba67f (refs/remotes/origin/celsus_0-1-0)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 0c533cf2327a416a254afa2348abafe7790ba67f # timeout=10
Commit message: "first embrio of container image"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 0c533cf2327a416a254afa2348abafe7790ba67f # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 40251
[build] $ /usr/lib/jvm/bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.13.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar:/usr/share/maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /usr/share/maven /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-4.5.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.13.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.13.jar 40251
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/bin/java" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:996)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:508)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:280)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:802)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 13 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Similar case as originated this case, as the different nature of the solutions proposed points out. I'd like to bring the attention that these errors having to do with permissions, or parsing of the pom might hide the real root cause, and error messages are not always as explicit and clear as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

I installed maven plugin for jenkins and provided the fully qualified path of pom.xml in root pom.xml and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this happens is maven has the right to run pom.xml ie. mvn command can be run through terminal but not through jenkins.
So we will need to add the current user to jenkins for it to work.

Follow this blogpost. It worked for me:

[blogpost](http://blog.manula.org/2013/03/running-jenkins-under-different-user-in.html)