# Permission denied while running shell bash command with lxc-container in jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, cicd, lxc

When running this block in Jenkinsfile:

```
String runTest = """
                #!/bin/bash
                if [ ${EXTRA_ENV} != "none" ]; then
                    echo "source extra environment file"
                    source ${WORKSPACE}/${upgradeEnvFile} //this one create a tmp.txt file
                fi
                cat tmp.txt
                """
            rc = sh(script: runTest, returnStatus: true)
```

I met this issue:

```
Cannot contact KVM-66: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/coolboy/workspace/DemoJob@tmp/durable-451e7be4/jenkins-log.txt (Permission denied)
```

When I access to the KVM and ls it:

```
total 84
drwxrwxr-x 3 coolboy coolboy  4096 Nov 15 16:37 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 coolboy coolboy   652 Nov 15 16:37 script.sh
-rwx------ 1 root    coolboy 65849 Nov 15 16:37 jenkins-log.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 coolboy coolboy     2 Nov 15 16:37 jenkins-result.txt
drwxrwxr-x 2 coolboy coolboy  4096 Nov 15 16:37 .
```

Somehow, the owner of 'jenkins-log' is changed to root. And, the 'tmp.txt' is created successfully.

I've tried these:
[permission denied in jenkins pipeline running bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739697/permission-denied-in-jenkins-pipeline-running-bash-script)
[Permission denied while running maven command jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749922/permission-denied-while-running-maven-command-jenkins)

But none of these works.
With the same job and configuration, it's always successful when running on ubuntu18.04.
My versions:

- Jenkins's version: 2.249.2
- KVM OS: ubuntu20.04
- Durable task's version: 1.35

I've set up new env with:

- Jenkins version: 2.375.3
- Durable task: 510.v324450f8dca_4

But still have the same issue.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The file is question is owned by root not the current jenkins user.  You could  try running the following:

```bash
sudo root
chown coolboy:coolboy jenkins-log.txt
```

Comment: Actually, the folder (which has jenkins-log) is created by durable task plugin. So I dont know exactly where I could insert chown command :D 
The weird thing is that my pipeline have many durable taskss (every task does have a jenkins-log file, and all of this is passed with root root permission). Only the block I mentioned is failed